# Condição com 4 valores

Tags: php, lógica

Opa, boa madrugada!

É o seguinte, preciso saber como eu faço o seguinte comparativo:
Tenho dois valores, marcação de entrada e saída, se o horário estiver marcado, o usuário não selecionar horário que estejam nesse meio tempo...

```
if(($hora_in > $hora_marcada_in && $hora_out < $hora_marcada_out)){
  echo 'PODE MARCAR';
  }else{
  echo 'NÃO PODE MARCAR';
}
```

Para entender melhor, se existe uma marcação das 14h00 às 16h00 o user não irá conseguir marcar valores que estejam no meio desses dois horários... 
ex: 15h00 às 17h00 ou 15h00 às 15h30... 
Eu tô perdidaço...

Agradecido dês de já!

Comment: O problema da sua tentativa é que você comparou entrada com entrada e saida com saida, sendo que tem que comparar assim `saida_pretendida <= entrada_existente || entrada_pretendida >= saida_existente` . Mais detalhes no link do box

Comment: Meu amigo! Muito obrigado! Eu não estava sabendo como procurar, desculpa pela duplicidade da questão!

Comment: Eu melhorei o título daquela, estava muito ruim de achar mesmo. Mas qq duvida quanto ao conteúdo, avise aqui que a gente tenta resolver. Normalmente você vai pegar o horário pretendido e fazer o teste que eu mencionei em cada um dos agendamentos já existentes num loop que percorra todos os agendamentos do dia. Caso haja agendamento possível durante a virada do dia, precisa fazer a comparação com o timestamp completo.

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez, eu meio que entendi a lógica, ele faz meio que uma verificação "de trás para frente"... Mas já apliquei e resolveu! Muito obrigado!

Comment: É uma situação que aparenta ter muitas condições, mas é simples, ou seu horário é antes ou é depois do existente :D qq outra condição é ocupado. Pra ser antes, tem que acabar antes do começo do próximo. Pra ser depois, tem que começar depois do fim do anterior.